# Weird golden moths flitting around my head in Skyrim Dragonborn

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I noticed this after doing about 4 of the Hermaeus Mora quests involving books, where you get to choose a perk at the end. My character has a cloud of golden particles flitting around the head like moths, and various people in cities tell me to 'be careful with that spell'.
What magical effect causes this, and is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: Would there be any clue under the "Active Effects" part of the magicka menu?

Comment: Have you been to the Ancestor Glade recently?  I seem to remember one quest there has you attracting golden "Ancestor Moths" http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ancestor_Glade

Comment: That was part of the Dawnguard quest to read one of the Elder Scrolls. I noticed this started after doing the Black Book quests.
I'm assuming it's due to some effect, but in the list of current effects enabled there's nothing related to ancestor moths.

Answer (score 2):

That sort of effect is usually applied to healing effects, spells or powers.  If none of your active effects mention anything to do with healing, then you may have just encountered a bug.  Skyrim's not exactly the most stable game, after all ;)